# Streamlit option_menu

Tags: python, streamlit

I am using option menu from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu to create a menu and it works fine but when I choose a option that calls for example second_menu.py and I want to display the menu in there it wont hide the first menu and both will show up. I would like to hide the first, any one please ?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve].